# First PDO syntax works, second similar one doesn't

Tags: php, syntax, pdo

I'm trying to create two databases after people fill out a signup form with their username, password, and email.

The first MySQL query below works. It inserts their info in the user table.

The second query doesn't though. It's trying to insert an encrypted key in the confirm table that I can use to confirm their account with a confirmation email.

Here's the PDO exception message:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'key, email) VALUES ( '24',
>   'd96e77df9072c73da2612380a784f51b', 'r' at line 1' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorspot\sign-up-tutors\index.php:80 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorspot\sign-up-tutors\index.php(80):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

```
if($action['result'] != 'error'){

$password = md5($password . 'salty');

    try
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO user (fullname, username, email, password, active) VALUES (
            :fullname,
            :username,
            :email,
            :password,
            0)';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
        $s->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->bindValue(':password', $password);
        $s->execute();
        //get the new user id
        $userid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error inserting signup info.';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tutorspot/inc/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    //create a random key for confirmation
    $key = $username . $email . date('mY');
    $key = md5($key . 'salty');

    //add info to confirm table

    try
    {   
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO confirm (userid, key, email) VALUES (
            :userid,
            :key,
            :email)';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
        $s->bindValue(':key', $key);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error inserting confirm info.';
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tutorspot/inc/error.html.php';
        echo $e;
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `USER`, which is the name of your table, is a MySQL reserved word. Don't use reserved words for table names or column names and if you do (which you should never do), use backticks to quote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` and `user` are reserved words in `SQL` syntax. Wrap your columns and table names in backticks. For example:

```
(`userid`, `key`, `email`)
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark/upvote next to this answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I tried to, but you answered so quickly hehe. It says "You can accept an answer in four minutes". I will click it after that time.